# Program is unable to see the data in tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am facing the following problem:

I have two programs.

The first program updates two Hive tables, say t1 and t2.

[In fact, at first the old tables are dropped and then two temp tables, say temp1 and temp2 are renamed to t1 and t2 respectively].

I have verified from the Hive CLI that the tables do exist and are populated.

The second program should read the tables t1 and t2. However, the program is unable to see any data in the tables.

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate and refresh the table metadata after the tables are re-created.

```
hiveContext.refreshTable('yourTableName')
```